# Lots of Parallelepiped

Tags: geometry, combinatorics

A,B,C,D are four points which ***are not on the same plane***.

> How many **different parallelepiped** can be constructed whose vertices are these points?

**Parallelepiped** is a solid figure with six faces having all parallelograms.

Comment: +1 Very nice question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The points could form any of the following configurations of vertices of the parallelepiped.
>
>  1. One vertex A together with its three adjacent vertices B,C,D. There are $4$ choices of which point is the central vertex A. The three edge directions of the parallelepiped are then AB, AC, AD, the order does not matter.
>   2. Vertices A,B,C,D where AB, BC, CD are adjacent pairs and so form edges of the parallelepiped. The four points can be labeled in $4!=24$ ways as A,B,C,D, but note that reversing the order gives exactly the same set of edges, so this leads to only $4!/2=12$ parallelepipeds.
>
>   Above are the only cases where we have three edges amongst pairs of points. It is not possible to have four, as that would mean the points form a side and so lie in a plane.
>  There could be two edges:
>
>  3. One vertex A, two vertices adjacent to it (B,C), and the vertex D diagonally opposite vertex A (D is not adjacent to any of A,B,C). There are $4$ choices for which point is A, $3$ for which other point is D, and the order of B,C does not matter. This gives $12$ parallelepipeds.
>
>  If we have and edge AB of the parallelepiped, there are only two vertices not adjacent to either A or B, and they form a plane. There is therefore no other way to have two edges, and no way to have only one edge amongst the given points. It is possible to have no edges though:
>
>  4. Vertices A,B,C,D where none of them are adjacent. Here the label ordering does not matter as they are all equivalent. This gives $1$ parallelepiped.
>
>   [image]
>
>  This gives a total of $4+12+12+1=29$ parallelepipeds.
>
>  Here is an animated gif showing all $29$ possibilities:
>
>  [image]

Comment: The diagram is really helpful here. +1

Comment: +1 for diagram, I know my answer is wrong when I saw the diagram.

Comment: @hexomino It also leads to a bit of confusion, at least for me. For example, case 1 has only 4 possibilities, not 8 because we are not choosing four of the vertices of an existing parallelepiped, but choosing a parallelepiped that uses the four points.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis is there any app for those diagram? i like your other diagram at triangle solitaire as well! pretty good!

Comment: @Oray: For this one I used MSPaint. For the solitaire question I took screenshots of [my own solitaire java app](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/solitapp.htm), cropped and reduced them, and edited some colours in MSPaint again.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I've got the feeling that you are considering only cuboids whereas the parallelepiped could be with sides which are rhombuses and not rectangles.

Comment: @rhsquared: No I'm not, or at least I don't think so. Nothing in the argument depends on the shape of the faces, only on which vertices share an edge. I did draw them as cubes in my picture, but that is just because those are easier to draw. When I have more time I may create a different picture.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good at combinatorics but I think the answer is:

Edit:

> 96 (24x4) because any 3 points are in one plane and the other one is not. Therefore we can draw a parallelepiped with a base formed by the 3 points and the 4th point being the point of the parallel parallelogram. We can then use the forth point to draw a side from any of the fourth points forming the base of the paralleliped. So we need to calculate the combinations without repetitions of 3 out 4 which is 4x3x2 = 24 and then multply the result by 4.

Answer (score 1):

> Should be 4?
>
> To make it easier to imagine, ABCD can form a tetrahedron.
> Every vertex of the tetrahedron can be a vertex of the parallelepiped.

Try to explain it more clearly

> A parallelepiped has 12 edges.
> When we focus on one of the vertex of the parallelepiped, each of the three edges attached to that vertex determine four edges of the parallelepiped.